# Joomla - Custom Field doesn't show-up on Edit/Update

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, cck

I've followed this [Tutorial](http://andresgallo.com/2011/08/22/add-custom-content-fields-to-joomla/comment-page-1) to add a custom field to the article content type and I was successful to make a new one with adding the following code:

`In File : root/administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml`

`Code :`

```
<field name="newText" type="editor" class="inputbox" 
label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_ARTICLETEXT_LABEL"
description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_ARTICLETEXT_DESC" 
filter="ContentHelper::filterText" buttons="true" />
```

`In File : root/administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php`

`Code :`

```
//Our new textbox
<div class="clr"></div>
<label>Article Text - New Text</label>
<div class="clr"></div>
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('newText'); ?>
```

and altered Database to add a new column for that new field.

`ALTER TABLE 'j_content' ADD 'newText' VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;`

On Article posting the data is successfully getting stored in Database.

The new custom field is visible when I'm posting a brand new article. But when I'm editing/updating the same new post, that newly added field is missing.

Is there a way to get this field even when we are editing the post/article.

Comment: Are you editing the post from the frontend or the backend?  Also - that article has recently been updated it looks like - did you see that?

Comment: It's really hard to say without code.

Comment: @Hanny This code has been added on the Backend and that particular field should only be visible to the Adminstrator. Sorry, I'm not aware of the updated article, I just found it and followed it in its current form.

Comment: @Elin I've added that code that is responsible for creating the new custom field. Hope that could help you to help me. Thanks

Comment: But what about the code you are using to retrieve it? What table are you storing it in? Is the field missing or is it that the data are missing?

Answer (score 1):

Please, never overwrite core files or change the core database! This is not a good tutorial because it is not update-safe.

If you need additional fields for your content items, use a special core extension for this instead.
I recommend this one:
http://fieldsattach.com/. This method is update-safe.